# Python Pandas .iloc Download columns by number

Tags: python, pandas

I want to download column numbers, eg 1,3,2. In the param.txt file I have only such an entry

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample1.csv')

with open('param.txt') as f:
  s = f.read()

  b = df.iloc[:, [s]] 
  print(b.to_string(index=False))
```

When I start a script

```
raise IndexError(f".iloc requires numeric indexers, got {arr}")
IndexError: .iloc requires numeric indexers, got ['1,3,2']
```

How to simply change from such a form to numeric

Thank you for every help

Answer (score 1):

This should work assuming f.read() returns "1,2,3"

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample1.csv')

with open('param.txt') as f:
  s = f.read() # Assuming this is a string such as "1,2,3"

  s = s.split(",") # Split string to list where there are commas ["1","2","3"]
  s = [int(x) for x in s] # Convert entries from string to int [1,2,3]

  b = df.iloc[:, s] # No need for brackets since s is already a list
  print(b.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer as a solution too :)